Is it possible to access IPv4 services from my IPv6-only AWS EC2 instance?
So I setup a new server with only public IPv6. While setting up, I realized I couldn't access certain services from the server. After further investigation I finally found out those services do not have an IPv6 DNS record.
I suppose they cannot know "who" my server is if it doesn't have an IPv4 right? Is there any solution without assigning an IPv4 to my server? I only need it one-way, I don't need IPv4 clients to connect to my server since the web service would be proxied through Cloudflare.

Found a solution from this article using NAT64:

Add the following three routes to the route table of the subnet containing the IPv6-only workloads:
IPv4 route (if any) pointing to the NAT gateway.
64:ff9b::/96 route pointing to the NAT gateway. This will allow traffic from your IPv6-only workloads destined for IPv4-only services to be routed through the NAT gateway.
IPv6 ::/0 route pointing to the egress-only internet gateway (or the internet gateway).
Note that pointing ::/0 to the internet gateway will allow external IPv6 hosts (outside the VPC) to initiate connection over IPv6.

Note that Internet NAT Gateway has a cost and you can use fuk-nat as a cheaper solution.

Correct, IPv4 and IPv6 are separate protocols, and need translation in transition technologies. If you are lucky enough to have an IPv4 address on the edge, this is fairly straightforward for egress on an entire network, NAT64 with DNS64.
In addition to NAT64 your outgoing traffic, request IPv6 from the things you use. Dual stack API end points could make this just work.
Support tickets on services, files issues with projects. A well run service will consider constructive feedback.
Now that legacy IP is a line item on public cloud bills, there is an obvious cost incentive. In addition to the technical reasons known for more than a decade. So IPv6 only will keep happening, increasing support burden for legacy only services.
